# How to add Xamarin PinView in cross platform app and set it as starting view?

Tags: xamarin

I want to add Pinview to this project and set it as starting page.
this is code view and the xaml.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PinView : ContentView
    {
        public PinView ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsPinView.Core;assembly=FormsPinView.Core" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="AllianceHire.Views.PinView">
   <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
         <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms!" />
      </StackLayout>
   </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Application base class offers the following features, which are
>   exposed in your projects default App subclass:

- A `MainPage` property, which is where to set the initial page for the    app.

So to set up  as PinView as starting page, go to `App.xaml.cs`, assign the PinView as `MainPage`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new PinView();
    }
}

public partial class PinView : ContentView
{
    public PinView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Read document about more detail information: [application-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class)

Comment: @ChamathViduranga Can you please mark it as an answer if it works for you?